# Any way of monitoring Airflow DAG's execution time?

Tags: monitoring, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'd like to use Airflow with Statsd and DataDog to monitor if DAG takes e.g. twice time as its previous execution(s). So, I need some kind of a real-time timer for a DAG (or `operator`).

I'm aware that Airflow supports [some metrics](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/metrics.html).
However, to my understanding all of the metrics are related to finished tasks/DAGs, right? So, It's not the solution, because I'd like to monitor running DAGs.

I also considered the [timeout_execution](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html#airflow.operators.BaseOperator)/[SLA](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#slas) features, but they are not suitable for this use-case

> I'd like to be notified that some DAG hangs, but I don't want to kill it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different ways you could handle this:

- In the past I've configured a telemetry DAG which would collect the current state of all tasks/DAGs by querying the metadata tables. I'd collect these metrics and push them up to CloudWatch. This became problematic as these internal fields change often so we would run into issues when trying to upgrade to newer versions of Airflow.
- There are also some well-maintained [Prometheus exporters](https://github.com/search?q=airflow+prometheus) that some companies have open sourced. By setting these up you could poll the exposed export path as frequently as you wanted to (DataDog [supports Prometheus](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/prometheus/)).

These are just some of your options. Since the Airflow webserver is just a Flask app you can really expose metrics in whatever way you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you can monitor running tasks in DAGs using DataDog, refer the integration with Airflow [docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/airflow/#overview)

You may refer metrics via DogStatD [docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/airflow/#data-collected). Also, look at this [page](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-airflow-with-datadog/) would be useful to understand what to monitor.

E.g., the metrics as below:

- `airflow.operator_failures`: monitor the failed operator.
- `airflow.operator_successes`: monitor succeed operator.
- `airflow.dag_processing.processes`: Number of currently running DAG parsing (processes).
- `airflow.scheduler.tasks.running` : Number of tasks running in executor
  Shown as task.